# Content Porter 2013: Select a component and any blueprinted children of said component

Tags: content-porter-2013

We've got a component in a Shared Content Publication (02) which is blueprinted to a Language Publication layer (05) and then localized in our Site Publication (09).

I want to get every instance of the component in mind and wanted to back these up by content porting it out of the Production CM.

My question: Is there any functionality within SDL Content Porter 2013 which would allow me to select the item that I want to content port from the 02 level and any items that stems from it? Instead of manually going through each 05 and 09 publications as there are 110+ publications to go through.

I've had a look through the documentation:

- http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Content%20Porter%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-C1220FE3-5BF2-4286-8C7B-C4D401A05691

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you refer the following [blog](http://tridioninternals.blogspot.com/2014/01/export-shared-items-from-owning.html). You can also code against the Import Export API of the content manager instance based on the scenarios highlighted [HERE](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-C1B075E6-7C62-450E-AFB5-77BB5C9C599F#docid=GUID-25E609B7-F0A1-4AC6-B65B-E368097D2FAD&filename=GUID-25E609B7-F0A1-4AC6-B65B-E368097D2FAD.xml&query=&scope=&tid=&resource=&inner_id=&addHistory=true&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-25E609B7-F0A1-4AC6-B65B-E368097D2FAD).

Comment: Yes...this was added exactly in the 2013 SP1 ("Export shared items from owning publications")